# Como posso contar o número de arquivos em uma pasta com PHP?

Tags: php, arquivo, diretório

Em PHP, qual é a maneira mais rápida e mais eficiente para se ler a quantidade de arquivos presentes em um determinado diretório.

Exemplificando, quero que a demonstração abaixo retorne `3`.

```
pasta/
    index.php
    dev.php
    .htaccess
    outra_pasta/
```

Quer dizer, quero que conte apenas os arquivos de uma pasta, ignorando as pastas que estão dentro da mesma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) para pegar os arquivos:

```
$arquivos = glob('/*.*'); //diretorio e padrão de arquivos que deve pegar
if (!$arquivos) echo count($arquivos);
else echo 'houve um erro';
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/jLuvv9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gtabeehh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://ideone.com/sQsSYo).

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais apropriada ao meu ver seria utilizando a classe `FileSystemIterator`, que faz parte do conjunto de classes padrão, oferecida pelo PHP.

```
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

echo iterator_count($iterator);
```

Nesse caso, temos que utilizar `SKIP_DOTS`, para não pegar as representações de diretórios como `.` e `..`.

**Observação**: A classe `FilesysteIterator` não implementa a interface `Countable`. Por isso é necessária a utilização da função `iterator_count`.